# Consume REST Hyperledger API from a web site

Tags: web-applications, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

is there any tutorial or way to consume the REST Hyperledger API generated in the playground from a hosted web site?
I`m looking for a tutorial step by step to consume the REST API from a web site NOT locally.

The idea is to develop the Smart Contracts with the playground.
In a hosted web application replace the MySQL data base with the REST Hyperledger API.

Thak you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to create a `composer-rest-server` in your server to be able to use it.

There is a tutorial here:
https://hackernoon.com/deploy-a-business-network-on-free-ibm-blockchain-starter-plan-93fafb3dd997

Comment: Hello Marckaraujo! Thank you so much for your response!
In a hosted web, I should do the same steps?

Comment: @Eese, Yes, you should.